# Is it safe to use abi.encodePacked in production solidity code?

Tags: solidity, keccak, bytes

In my solidity game project, I am using this:

```
if (king == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(player)){
   //continue as king
} else{
  // not king
}
```

Where player data type is `bytes` and `king` is a player address. Does this look good or could it be tricked if `player` is controlled by user input? I think `keccak256` would prevent it, wouldn't it?

Comment: `king` is type `address`? If so, the equality check is weird... Also note that `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(player))` will always return the same result for the same `player`value. If the user can control the `player` value directly, the equality can be controlled too. In general though, `abi.encodePacked` is perfectly well behaved and can be used in production systems.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi, `king` is of type `byte32` . Hm, but let's say even if user knows the value of `king` even tho it is private variable. Then, still they cannot control a `player` value in a way that keccak256 returns as same as that. Or do they?

Comment: I don't know. You have not provided any details about how the `player` value is set...

Comment: It's non-deterministic, It's like `first2byteof_contractaddr+<24_digit_hex_seed>+remainingbyteof_contractaddr` where contractaddr == generated contract address @ShawnTabrizi

Answer (score 6):

The function `abi.encodePacked()` only concatenates its input data in a bytes array in memory it doesn't transform the data in any way. So it is totaly safe to use in production code.

The function `keccak256()` is a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). One of its properties is that is computationally hard to find a preimage, ie given `king` is in practice impossible to find the value of `player`.